# How to capture this value in GTM data layer using JS code?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am completely new to JS/coding, etc. and hope you can help me. I would like to inject document.getElementById("ID VALUE").value into GTM data layer using a JS code - see below:

While testing, I can see 'undefined' in data layer. What code should I use in order to have document.getElementById("ID VALUE").value from the page console in data layer?

I've tried different codes, but can only see 'undefined' values in data layer.

```
function() {
var field = document.getElementById("ID VALUE").value;  
field = Number(field.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,"")); 
  
return field ? field : undefined;
}

    

function() {
  var inputField = document.getElementById("myFormField");
  return inputField.value || "";
}
```